# How to delete a pointer to an array of objects without deleting the objects themselves? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, destructor, std-pair

I've got a pointer to a set of pairs - pair(K, V)* myPairs - and the instance in question is with (string, Set(string)) where Set is a binary search tree class. I'm trying to create a function that doubles the size of myPairs, so I:

- create newPairs and copy over the data from myPairs
- delete myPairs
- set myPairs to newPairs

The problem is that deleting myPairs also calls the destructor for the associated Sets, but I still want to access that data. How can I avoid this???

Comment: Please show a  [mcve] of what the problem is (e.g.: why is it a problem that the destructor of the original objects is being called)

Comment: "_I've got a pointer to a set of pairs..._" - why? Why not simply use a `std::set` (or a `std::vector`)?

Comment: That's likely an issue with your set class. Deleting the moved/copied from set shouldn't affect the new set.

Comment: The copying step should have taken care of this for you. Make sure you correctly observed the [Rule of Three or Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Five sounds like it may be a better fit here than Three.

Comment: Voting to close this for now. Not a line of code. Guessing games are pointless.

Comment: "How to delete a pointer to ..."  Did you allocate the pointer with a `new`? If not you can't delete it. You probably created the pointer with a new to the set of pairs and deleted what the pointer pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

> How to delete a pointer to an array of objects without deleting the objects themselves? C++

You don't. Elements of an array are part of the array. There is no way around that.

> How can I avoid this???

Use another data structure. If you need to resize the data structure, and you need elements to remain valid when you resize it, then array is not an option. Node based data structures can do this. You want a set, and the standard library comes with `std::set` which happens to satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't access an array's elements if the array itself is lost!

When you create an array, All it's elements are stored in the memory allocated to the array itself. Unless you allocate memory to them explicitly, the data (in this case, your objects) will be destroyed along with the array.

> How to fix it?: **Go dynamic**.
>   Use the heap for your help. Create your array dynamically.

The reason being, Objects created in heap memory don't get destroyed along with the pointer unless you command it *explicitly*.

You can delete your pointer now, and your array still remains in the storage.